# Is an exploit that exposes the balance of any account in the bank a high risk exploit?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, banks, ethics

I have found an exploit to get account balance information for any account in my bank website.

What is the level of this exploit (risk, medium, low)?

and is it ethical to ask for a prize or money before telling them what is the problem?

Comment: it's just information disclosure and a high privacy risk - yes, it's unethical to demand payment for a problem you have found

Comment: In agreement with @schroeder. It's definitely unethical to *demand* payment, but there's no harm in politely asking for it after providing details. Demanding payment makes you an extortionist. No one wants to work with an extortionist.

Comment: ok forget about the ethics part , is it legal to ask for money  ?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a leak of sensitive information. Privacy demands that as an account holder my bank balance is not disclosed to random individuals. Some people might not be bothered by such a disclosure, but most will consider it a breach of their privacy.

> What is the level of this exploit (risk, medium, low)?

This is subjective to the environment but I would say in this case the risk to privacy is 'high'.

> is it ethical to ask for a prize or money before telling them what is
>   the problem?

Answer to this is, again, subjective. Do they have a bug bounty program where they are offering rewards for such disclosures? If yes, then it is ethical for you to report the issue and claim the reward. If they do not have a bounty program, I would write an email to their IT or security team with details of your findings without expecting anything but a 'thank you' (which you might or might not get).

In case you receive no response from them and they do not patch the vulnerability, you might want to go for full disclosure in a public forum after waiting a certain period of time.

Comment: Small note, before going full disclosure, better get some evidence that the bank really received your message. (With emails, this is a bit hard). And rather than doing it right away after a single message, press them, and involve some regulation authority first instead of the media or whatever. ... Harming a big company can come back to bite you, that's why. Especially with judges all over the world that have not the slightest idea of common sense and technical stuff.

Comment: A good way to go could be to involve the banks countries CERT or that of your country with the responsible disclosure. Thus, there's evidence and they might have more influence on the bank and make the problem heard.

Comment: ok forget about the ethics part , is it legal to ask for money  ?